# YouTube get_video_info выдает ошибку 105

Tags: php, youtube

```
"http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$id
```

Иногда в ответе выдает ошибку 105 и написано оно от какого-нибудь партнера и он запретил просмотр его на других сайтах. Не знаете, как это обойти?

К примеру, у этого видео **`http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=IN12-xVLt7M`**.
Вот ответ сервера:

> `status=fail&errorcode=150&reason=Это видео содержит контент от партнера X Media Digital. На некоторых веб-сайтах его просмотр ограничен.
> <br/>
> <u>
>     <a href='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN12-xVLt7M&feature=player_embedded' target='_blank'>Просмотр на YouTube</a>
> </u>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$id.'&asv=3&eurl=http://vkontakte.ru/&el=embedded';
```

Укажи хост vk. Мне это помогало.